# Can't render image from the project folder

Tags: image, png

I can't render the image which I have in my project directory src/images/.
I tried to add image-loader to the project but even this doesn't help.
[image]

Here's part of my code:

```
    import React from 'react';
import './styles/styles.scss';

const App = () =>
<div className = "container">
  <div className="header">
    <img id="ava" src="../src/images/img.png"></img>
    <h3>@kkdimaa</h3>
  </div>
  <img src="https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Twitter_logo_bird_transparent_png.png" className='image' alt="Alps"/>
</div>

export default App;
```

full repo: https://github.com/dimakononenko/react-drafts

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    `import img from './src/images/img.jpg'` (check the path)
```

and in the return function,

```
    `<img
        src={img}
        id="ava"
    />`
```

Comment: After changes it renames the image in the source code, which is a progress.
But the image itself still crashes on the browser

Comment: Can you please explain why I need to import image like that?
Shouldn't that be working without any imports by default?